# AngularJS : pass data from controller to controller without factory, service or broadcast?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I don't want to use a service or a factory and would like to pass for example an array of data. I would like to access data in my parent controller from my child component.

Factory and service are excluded since i eventually want to migrate my app to angular 2, and i don't want to use ngclick which seems inseperable with broadcast/up/on. 
If anyone knows how to pass data on the background (without user interaction, like input or ngclick) using broadcasting, it would work aswell :)

What are my options ?
Thank you !

Comment: Sorry to say, but you exclude a factory & service as a answer, although these `service / factory - singleton` approaches were born to do exactly that. Bad practice not to use them as solution. Maybe it has a reason?

Comment: It's a HORRIBLE idea to discard factories and services, and you SHOULD do it. But if you absolutely HAVE to, you can use $rootScope. http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYFPsn0JMBNsiO0G4qNh

Comment: It's because i eventually would like to migrate my app to angular 2, and therefore would like only to use controllers... Or am i going trying to hard for something too easy?

Comment: If you have a components based architecture then your approach is correct @William D

Comment: use a flux store that is outside angular

Comment: @gyc, exactly, i have a component based architecture, what should i do then? :)

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#services ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have nested components, you can access the parent's data with `require`

```
var child = {
    bindings: {},
    require: {
        parent: '^^parent'
    },
    controller: childController,
    templateUrl: 'child.template.html'
};
```

Now in your child controller you have access to an instance of the parent controller and thus can call methods and access it's properties:

```
this.parent.parentMethod();
```

You have some more detailed code in a previous answer here:

[Where should I place code to be used across components/controllers for an AngularJS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305782/where-should-i-place-code-to-be-used-across-components-controllers-for-an-angula/38307456#38307456)

Your other choices:

### bindings

Just like directives' `scope` or `bindToController` you can bind data and methods through html attributes using the `bindings` propety of your component

```
<component-x shared="$ctrl.shared"></component-x>

var componentX = {
    bindings: { shared: '=' }
    ...
```

### $rootScope

Never use it to store data. It works but it's not made for that purpose and will lead to unmaintainable code.

### Services

It's a common misconception that shared data should be done through services.
It was true and good practice before 1.5 though.

### Controller inheritance

Another bad practice (imo).
In a *classic* MVC app nested controllers can inherit parents with the `$controller` service:

```
.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.logMessage = function(message) {
        console.log("Message: " + message);
    }

})

.controller('ServicesController', function($scope, $controller) {
    $controller('MainController', {$scope: $scope});
});
```

### Broadcast and emit Events

It's the way to go if the event you're broadcasting makes sense application wide (login, logout...etc.) If you're updating a variable in a component, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to use a service or a factory and would like to pass for
>   example an array of data

You can use localStorage/sessionStorage to store and fetch the data

Comment: This could use a short example.