# Few questions regarding controllerAs

Tags: angularjs

As much as i have read all the questions in SO, i still have few questions here around the controllerAs, using generic widget directive below as example

```
var app = angular.module('test')
app.directive('genericDirective', function(){
  return {
      restrict:'E',
      templateUrl: someUrlHere,
      scope: { someScopeHere },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function(){
         someControllerHere
      }
  }
})
```

And the template for the directive above is

```
<div>{{info1}} {{info2}} {{info3}}</div>
```

And say there are like few directives above (genericDirective2, genericDirective3 and so on) that uses same setup as above. My idea here is to have a generic directive that can be plug-in into any view and works with any controllers that handle the view which the directive above is in.

So say if i have a layout below

```
<div id="someId" ng-controller="thisController">
    <!-- Widget one -->
    <generic-directive1></generic-directive1>
    <!-- Widget two -->
    <generic-directive2></generic-directive2>
    <!-- Widget three -->
    <generic-directive3></generic-directive3>
</div>
```

Assume that thisController gets a json, which contains all the data needed to render each directive accordingly

```
{
    "generic-directive-1": {
        "id": "someId1",
        "class": "someClass1",
        "data": {
            "info1":"someInfo1-1",
            "info2":"someInfo1-2",
            "info3":"someInfo1-3"
        }
    },
    "generic-directive-2": {
        "id": "someId2",
        "class": "someClass2",
        "data": {
            "info1":"someInfo2-1",
            "info2":"someInfo2-2",
            "info3":"someInfo2-3"
        }
    },
    "generic-directive-3": {
        "id": "someId3",
        "class": "someClass3",
        "data": {
            "info1":"someInfo3-1",
            "info2":"someInfo3-2",
            "info3":"someInfo3-3"
        }
    }
}
```

How can i make it so that

- thisController can access to specific genericDirective using the controllerAs (in this case using controllerAs: 'vm'), say if i want to pass specific params from thisController to generic-directive-3, how can i do it?
- The right directive will get the right data from thisController? Since i set all directives with controllerAs:'vm'.
- Do i need to use different controllerAs name for each directive? As 2-3 of the directives with the same controllerAs might be used within a page, and the page controller might be referring to the wrong directive?

Comment: based on your questions, your template, and your JSON, it's clear your understanding of how directives and scope work is flawed.  it's best to think of each directive as it's own mini angular application, designed to work independently of your main app.  If you have `controllerAs: 'vm'` in the directive, then the directive's template (and **only** this template) will use `vm.info1`.  The parent or other sibling directives aren't going to have access to this ***specific instance*** of `vm`.  Therefore, the parent must provide the values to the directive, via HTML attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i make it so that thisController can access to specific
>   genericDirective using the controllerAs (in this case using
>   controllerAs: 'vm'), say if i want to pass specific params from
>   thisController to generic-directive-3, how can i do it?

Since you're not using components, the cleanest way to share data between controllers is by using services. [You also have other choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698953/angularjs-pass-data-from-controller-to-controller-without-factory-service-or/38699338#38699338).

In the case of directives, you can / should pass data through attributes:

```
<div id="someId" ng-controller="thisController">
    <generic-directive1 data="obj.generic-directive-1"></generic-directive1>
    <generic-directive2 data="obj.generic-directive-2"></generic-directive2>
    ...
</div>
```

This data will be bound to the scope of the directive or to the directives's controller. I wouldn't personnaly use them together as it can become confusing:

```
  return {
      restrict:'E',
      template: '<p>{{data.id}}</p>',
      scope: { data: '=' }
  }
```

or

```
  return {
      restrict:'E',
      template: '<p>{{vm.data.id}}</p>',
      bindToController: { 'data: '=' },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      controller: function() {
         console.log(this.data); //data is bound to the controller
      }
  }
```

> The right directive will get the right data from thisController? Since
>   i set all directives with controllerAs:'vm'.

The directive will get the data through the scope if an isolated scope is used or directly through the controller if `bindToController` is used.

> Do i need to use different controllerAs name for each directive? As
>   2-3 of the directives with the same controllerAs might be used within
>   a page, and the page controller might be referring to the wrong
>   directive?

You don't have to use a different name for the controllerAs property as it's only used inside the directive.

However in order to avoid repeating controller code, you cannot declare it as n anonymous function inside the directive but rather like so:

```
function UniqueController() {
  console.log("hello");
}

function myDirective1() {
  return {
      restrict:'E',
      template: '<p>{{vm.data.id}}</p>',
      bindToController: { 'data: '=' },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      controller: UniqueController
  }
}

angular.module('mymodule', []);
angular.module('mymodule')
    .directive('myDirective1', myDirective1)
    .directive('myDirective2', myDirective2)
    .controller('UniqueController', UniqueController);
```

Comment: I have another question. Say inside that directive, i want to access the event on that specific directive only (like click event) from thisController. How do i refer to that click event from that specific directive in thisController?

Comment: Hard to do in comment section. You either pass ng-click to the directive, or pass an attribute myonclick=functionClick() that you can bind in the directive with myonclick: '&'. Then inside the directive you should have a link function where you register click events or you can do that in the directive's controller. For more details post another question.