# angular get result of one component in another component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm really new to angular and trying to figure out how to get component functions to talk to each other.

I have a phone-list.component.js in which I do a HTTP get that relies on a session variable:

```
angular.
  module('phoneList').
  component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: '/phone-list.template.html',
    controller: ['$http',
      function PhoneListController($http) {
        var self = this;

        var access_token = '';



          var data = $.param({
              grant_type: 'password',
              username: 'test',
              password: 'test',
              client_id:'1234',
              client_secret:'12345',
          });

          var config = {
              headers : {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
              }
          }

          $http.post('/o/token/', data, config)
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              self.access_token = data['access_token'];
              console.log(access_token);
          })
          .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
              $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                  "<hr />status: " + status +
                  "<hr />headers: " + header +
                  "<hr />config: " + config;
          });


          var header = {
                  headers : {
                      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+self.access_token
                  }
              }

        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'api/posts/', headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+self.access_token}}).then(function(response) {
          self.phones = response.data;

        });
      }
    ]
  });
```

I generate the variable in another module that looks like this in a file called authentication.component.js:

```
angular.module('authentication').factory('authenticationService', function($http, $se){
    function authenticate(){
        $http.post('/o/token/', data, config)
              .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                  console.log('auth service: '+data['access_token']);
                  $sessionStorage.access_token = data['access_token'];
              });
    }    
    function getToken(){
        return $sessionStorage.access_token;
    }
    return {
        authenticate:authenticate,
        getToken:getToken
    };
});
```

My app.module.js looks like this:

```
angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'phoneList',
  'authentication',
]);
```

My phone-list.module.js looks like this:

```
angular.module('phonecatApp', [
  // ...which depends on the `phoneList` module
  'phoneList',
  'authentication',
]);

angular.module('phoneList', []);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have http calls in components. Move to a service and have it injected

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305782/where-should-i-place-code-to-be-used-across-components-controllers-for-an-angula/38307456#38307456

Comment: @Phix do you have a link to how I do that?